# Image with laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Problem with laravel Image:

I have my code to store the image and it is:

```
$img = Image::make(asset('public/storage/assets/'.$product->image));

$img->insert(asset('template/images/logo-1000frases-w.png'), 'bottom-left', 10, 10);

$img->save(public_path('public/storage/assets/'.$product->image));
```

I add a watermark on the image and then I store it.

The problem is.. when I try to store the image it says:

```
Unable to init from given url (http://138.197.121.221/public/storage/assets/ijTdImC4dIcobYa1QSDA59oDiF8J8e0FjQS1EG3n.jpeg).
```

But I have the correct path...  public, storage, assets, all of them exist; I wonder what could it be?

Thanks!

Comment: public path starts from from `public/` folder you need to remove `public/` from `asset()`.

Comment: Hmmm it still shows the problema :/

Comment: You should use `storage_path()` not `public_path()` for example: 
`$img->save(storage_path('assets/'.$product->image));`

Comment: Image::make() requires path as parameter no URL

Answer (score 2):

you may upload your imgae in laravel 5 using this way

```
        $image=$request->file('image');
        $fileName=$image->getClientOriginalName();
        $path = $image->move('storage/assets/',$fileName); 
        $folderPath=url('/).''.'/uploads/blog/'.''.$fileName;
```

image is your key for request image.  $folderPath variable is use for save in your database table. This may work for you

Comment: This does not attempt to answer what was wrong in the original question.

Comment: Thanks! it gave me some ideas.

Answer (score 0):

I could get a solution:

```
$file = $request->file('image');
$fileName = time() . '-' . $file->getClientOriginalName();
$path = $file->move('storage/assets/',$fileName);
```

Then:

```
$img = Image::make($path);
$img->insert(asset('template/images/logo-1000frases-w.png'), 'bottom-left', 10, 10);
$img->save(public_path('storage/assets/'.$product->image));
```

And this is it! :D